Can the Sea Peoples be considered a different faction or a unified ethnicity?
I’m new to the world of history, so I hope you’ll bear with me!
I’ve been diving into the topic of the Sea Peoples and keep coming across the idea that they were a mix of different ethnic groups. But I’m curious about how a bunch of different groups could pull off such huge attacks that seriously disrupted civilizations like the Mycenaeans and the Hittites.
Here are a few things I’m wondering about:
Coordination of Attacks: If the Sea Peoples were made up of various groups, how did they manage to work together so effectively for these massive attacks? For comparison, Genghis Khan was able to unite different groups, but even he had to deal with internal conflicts, like with Jamukha. There’s no clear evidence of internal strife among the Sea Peoples, which makes me wonder if they might have been more unified than we think.
Origins and Adaptation: Most of their attacks were in regions like the Middle East and parts of Africa. To win battles in such tough terrains, like the Nile Delta, they’d need to be really familiar with the area. This makes me think they might have come from somewhere nearby or from a place with similar conditions.

Have you checked the Wikipedia article on the Sea Peoples?

"There’s no clear evidence of internal strife among the Sea Peoples" - there's not much clear evidence of anything else about the Sea Peoples.

Interesting question, but (a) Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient. and (b) I'm ... skeptical of your analogies to Chinggis Khan. I'm not sure how much we knew about Jamukha until the modern era - My hypothesis is that contemporary views of the horde were quite similar to contemporary views of the Sea Peoples.  Victims of successful plunder perceive the opponents as organized.

How unified do you consider the Vikings to have been (as one example)?

Can the sea people be considered?  Yes, you clearly do.  But is there evidence for that conclusion?   No

This might be an interesting dissertation topic, but not one that anyone can tackle in the SE Q&A model.

We don't know.
We have very little information about the Sea Peoples, although there are a lot of hypotheses. The name was created by Egyptologists around the beginning of the 20th century, and is not used in the ancient sources, which name individual groups, which we identify with varying degrees of certainty.
The information we have is from sources who weren't recording history in the modern sense, which had not been invented at the time. It's very possible that multiple events have been conflated in the ancient sources, and we don't know what other misrepresentations might have been made.
The groups that have been identified probably came from different parts of the Eastern Mediterranean basin. That has been well-travelled since well before the era where the Sea Peoples are identified. It's quite possible, for example, that one group raided the Nile Delta, did well, and word got around, prompting raids by other groups later in the same year or the next year. A couple of decades later, a scribe could well have merged several raids for the political purposes of the moment, and that happened to be the record that survived.
We just don't have enough information for firm conclusions.

This is roughly the answer I was thinking of making. I'd add that even the term itself was not used in ancient sources. Its entirely an invention of "Egyptologists" around the beginning of the 20th century. Ancient sources themselves tended to just mention specific groups of people (who we may or may not know the origins of). It was the Egyptologists who decided to throw them all together and call them "Sea Peoples". Its kind of like calling all Medieval horse-borne raiders into Europe "Altaic Pastorlists" (except perhaps more compressed in time).

@T.E.D. Or Germanic invaders of Rome "Germanic invaders"?

@T.E.D.: Added.
